# How to make Async Await Function in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await

I want to create a function that is about uploading photo to Firebase Storage with `react-native-fetch-blob`. I'm using Redux and you can find action functions below:

My problem is that uploadImage function is not running like asynchronous. Firebase function is running before uploadImage, so application give me an error.

I think i can't make a asynchronous function. How can i fix it ?

**uploadImage() function:**

```
const uploadImage = async (imageSource, whereToUpload) => {
  let imageURL = '';
  const mime = 'image/jpg';
  const { Blob } = RNFetchBlob.polyfill;
  const { fs } = RNFetchBlob;

  window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
  window.Blob = Blob;

  console.log('URI =>', imageSource.uri);

  let imgUri = imageSource.uri;
  let uploadBlob = null;
  const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref(whereToUpload + '/' + imageSource.fileName);
  const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? imgUri.replace('file://', '') : imgUri;
  await fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
  .then((data) => Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` }))
  .then((blob) => {
    uploadBlob = blob;
    return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
  })
  .then(() => {
    uploadBlob.close();
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
    return imageURL = imageRef.getDownloadURL();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  return imageURL;
};
```

**and the main action is:**

```
export const addProjectGroup = (
  myUser,
  groupName,
  groupDescription,
  groupProfilePic,
) => dispatch => {
  const groupProfileFinalPic = async () => {
    let finalGroupPicture = { landscape: '' };

    if (_.isEmpty(groupProfilePic.src)) {
      await uploadImage(groupProfilePic, 'groupPictures').then((imageURL) => {
      console.log('İŞLEM TAMAM!');
      console.log('SELECTED IMAGE URL =>', imageURL);
      finalGroupPicture.landscape = imageURL;
    });
    } else {
      finalGroupPicture.landscape = groupProfilePic.src.landscape;
    }
    return finalGroupPicture;
};

console.log("final group profile pic =>", groupProfileFinalPic());

  // Önce grubu yaratalım..
  // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring
  const key = firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .child('groups')
    .push().key;

  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/groups/' + key)
    .set({
      admin: {
        email: myUser.email,
        name: myUser.name,
        uid: myUser.uid,
      },
      groupName,
      groupDescription,
      groupProfilePic: groupProfileFinalPic(),
      projects: '',
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Groups oluşturuldu.');
    })
    .catch(e => {
      Alert.alert('Hata', 'Beklenmedik bir hata meydana geldi.');
      console.log(e.message);
    });

  dispatch({
    type: ADD_PROJECT_GROUP,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not awaiting `groupProfileFinalPic()`. This should be done before creating the action you want to dispatch.

```
groupProfileFinalPic().then(groupProfilePic => {
    return firebase
        .database()
        .ref("/groups/" + key)
        .set({
            admin: {
                email: myUser.email,
                name: myUser.name,
                uid: myUser.uid
            },
            groupName,
            groupDescription,
            groupProfilePic,
            projects: ""
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Groups oluşturuldu.");
        })
        .catch(e => {
            Alert.alert("Hata", "Beklenmedik bir hata meydana geldi.");
            console.log(e.message);
        });
});
```

I have no clue what the last dispatch is for, you might want to do that in one of the callbacks. Your code is to verbose for an SO question, but I hope this helps anyways.

Comment: Can you explain with fixing code please ? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both `await` and `then` on the same call.   To use `await`, you can arrange it something like

```
const uploadImage = async (imageSource, whereToUpload) => {
    ...
    try {
        let data = await RNFS.fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
        let uploadBlob = await Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` }))
        ...etc...
        return finalResult
    catch (e) {
        // handle error
    }


}
```